# ASP.net MVC Razor - binding checkboxs to bool values

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, boolean

I can't figure out how to get selected checkboxes to become "true" and unselected checkboxes to become "false" bool values. Here is a sample of the code I am working on.

Note: My put function is getting a 200 response but the checkboxes just are not updating the bool.

Model

```
public class AccountFeatures
        { public bool? FormCopy { get; set; }
            public bool? FormRename { get; set; }
            public bool? FormTransfer { get; set; }
            public bool? FormDelete { get; set; }
            public bool? FormEdit { get; set; }
            public bool? FormComplete { get; set; }
        }
```

View

```
`$('.ui.form.accountfeatures').form({
            on: 'blur',
            inline: true,
            onSuccess: function () {
                $('#features').dimmer('show');
                $.ajax({
                    method: 'PUT',
                    data: { FormRename: $("#FormRename").val() ? true : false,
                        FormTransfer: $("#FormTransfer").val() ? true : false,
                        FormDelete: $("#FormDelete").val() ? true : false,
                        FormEdit: $("#FormEdit").val() ? true : false,
                        FormComplete: $("#FormComplete").val() ? true : false}
```

HTML

```
<tr>
                    <td>Form Copy</td>
                    <td class="center aligned">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="FormCopy" id="FormCopy" value="False" checked="@Model.Account.Features.FormCopy">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Form Rename</td>
                    <td class="center aligned">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="FormRename" id="FormRename" value="FormRename" checked="@Model.Account.Features.FormRename">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Form Transfer</td>
                    <td class="center aligned">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="FormTransfer" id="FormTransfer" value="FormTransfer" checked="@Model.Account.Features.FormTransfer">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Form Delete</td>
                    <td class="center aligned">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="FormDelete" id="FormDelete" value="FormDelete" checked="@Model.Account.Features.FormDelete">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Form Edit</td>
                    <td class="center aligned">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="FormEdit" id="FormEdit" value="FormEdit" checked="@Model.Account.Features.FormEdit">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Form Complete</td>
                    <td class="center aligned">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="FormComplete" id="FormComplete" value="FormComplete" checked="@Model.Account.Features.FormComplete">
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

Comment: You manual html is setting the checked property for every checkbox (the presence of a `checked` attribute means its checked) an your `value` attributes have not relationship to a `bool` (a `bool` can only be bound to `true` or `false`, not a `string`) - use the strongly typed `HtmlHelper` methods to generate you html

Answer (score 4):

I typically use an `EditorFor` and it just works:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.CheckBoxProperty)
```

However, I also typically only use `bool`, not `bool?` for my checkbox properties.

Something to note regarding the `checked` attribute - you usually either use just the attribute name, as in:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="FormComplete" id="FormComplete" value="FormComplete" checked />
```

Or you use `checked="checked"`, as in:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="FormComplete" id="FormComplete" value="FormComplete" checked="checked" />
```

Any other way, like putting `checked="true"` or `checked="false"` doesn't produce the outcome that you would expect, or at the very least, is not consistent amongst all browsers. What these use cases usually result in are checked boxes, regardless of whether you wanted that, or not. Here's a quick mock up to demonstrate:

```html
<input type="checkbox" value="test" name="test1" /> Test 1<br />
<input type="checkbox" value="test" name="test2" checked /> Test 2<br />
<input type="checkbox" value="test" name="test3" checked="checked" /> Test 3<br />
<input type="checkbox" value="test" name="test4" checked="true" /> Test 4<br />
<input type="checkbox" value="test" name="test5" checked="false" /> Test 5
```

And a screenshot of the output under Chrome 57:

[image: Screenshot]

Essentially, you want to use logic to determine whether to insert the `checked` attribute altogether, rather than inserting it and having the logic set it to true or false.