# set checkboxes to checked in view depending on condition

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, checkbox, checked

I have list of objects

```
        AAA.aListofObjects= (from tdrc in db.objectsDB
                                      where tdrc.objectID == id
                           select tdrc).ToList();
```

one parameter AAA.aListofObjects.check - holds true or false data.

Inside view I render my list using "for" where I have "If" statement to decide whether to check or not the checkbox

```
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.aListofObjects.Count; i++)
    {
if(something equals something then I must render checkbox as checked)
{
 @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => modelItem.aListofObjects[i].check)
}
else 
{
render unchecked checkbox
 @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => modelItem.aListofObjects[i].check)
}

    }
```

Now how can I make them checked in this situation ?
 `@Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => modelItem.aListofObjects[i].check, @checked="checked")` does not help.

some aListofObjects[i].check are "true" and when I check html debugger I see that checkbox has value="true" status, but it is still unchecked. Why ?

Comment: Can't you just bind the value of `something equals something then I must render checkbox as checked` to the checkbox? https://stackoverflow.com/a/43551907/169714

Comment: If the value of the property is `true`, then the checkbox will be checked. If its `false` it will not be. That is how model binding works. You do not need and `if/else` block, and you do not set the `checked` attribute (the `CheckBoxFor()` method sets it correctly based on the value of the property)

Comment: Related issues: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46804274/check-the-checkbox-based-on-model-in-mvc & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6157293/how-do-i-set-a-checkbox-in-razor-view. The assignment for `CheckBoxFor` is redundant and you should set checked state on viewmodel property.

Comment: Exactly what I said. You could also use the general `Html.EditorFor`. Because the property is a bool it will render a checkbox.

Comment: some aListofObjects[i].check are "true" and when I check html debugger I see that checkbox has value="true" status, but it is still unchecked. Why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In true condition to make checkbox checked you can set below code :

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => modelItem.aListofObjects[i].check, new { @checked = "checked" })
```

And for else condition to remain checkbox uncheck you can set below code :

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => modelItem.aListofObjects[i].check)
```

And you can get more details on **@HTML.CheckboxFor** here : [Proper usage of .net MVC Html.CheckBoxFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12674572/proper-usage-of-net-mvc-html-checkboxfor)[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12674572/proper-usage-of-net-mvc-html-checkboxfor)